# 2 XMLHTTPRequests in one Javascript (Dynamics CRM)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am currently trying to run 2 separate XMLHTTPRequests in dynamics CRM Javascript to retrieve data from 2 different entities and run code depending on what is retrieved..

I've done my best to try and edit some names for security reasons, but the premise is the same.
My main problem is that the first run of the XMLHTTPRequest (the RA Banner) works fine, but then the second run (the Status Banner) the Readystate that is returned is 2 and stopping.

```
function FormBanners(formContext) {
    //Clear the existing banners
    formContext.ui.clearFormNotification("Notif1");
    formContext.ui.clearFormNotification("Notif2");

    //Get the customer/rep
    var customer = formContext.getAttribute("customerid").getValue();
    var rep = formContext.getAttribute("representative").getValue();
    var contact;

    //use the rep if there is one else use the customer
    if (rep != null) {
        contact = rep;
    }
    else if (customer!= null) {
        contact = customer;
    }

    //Get the account
    var account = formContext.getAttribute("accountfield").getValue();

    //As there is a requirement for 2 XMLHTTPRequests we have to queue them
    var requestURLs = new Array();

    //There will always be a customers or rep on the form
    requestURLs.push(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$select=new_RA,new_SC,new_VC,new_PR&$filter=contactid eq " + contact[0].id + "", true);

    //there may not be an account
    if (account) {
        requestURLs.push(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=_new_statusLookup_value&$filter=accountid eq " + account[0].id + "", true);
    }

    var current = 0;

    function getURL(url) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", requestURLs[current]);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(req.response);
                    // Creation of the RA Banner
                    if (current == 0) {
                        var RA = result.value[0]["new_RA@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        var SC = result.value[0]["new_SC@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        var VC = result.value[0]["new_VC@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        var PR = result.value[0]["new_PR@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        var Notif = "";

                        //Only create a notification if any of the above contain "Yes"
                        if (RA == "Yes" || SC == "Yes" || VC == "Yes" || PR == "Yes") { Notif = "The Customer/Rep has:" }
                        if (RA == "Yes") { Notif = Notif + " RA,"; }
                        if (SC == "Yes") { Notif = Notif + " SC,"}
                        if (VC == "Yes") { Notif = Notif + " VC,"}
                        if (PR == "Yes") { Notif = Notif + " PR."}

                        if (Notif != "") {
                            formContext.ui.setFormNotification(Notif, "INFO", "Notif1");
                        }
                    }
                    //Creation of the Status Banner
                    else if (current == 1) {
                        status = results.value[i]["_new_statusLookup_value"];
                        if (status) {
                            if (status[0].name != "Open")
                                var Notif = "The status for the organisation on this case is " + status[0].name + ".";
                            formContext.ui.setFormNotification(Notif, "INFO", "Notif2");
                        }
                    }

                    ++current;
                    if (current < requestURLs.length) {
                        getURL(requestURLs[current]);
                    }

                } else {
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }; req.send();
    }

    getURL(requestURLs[current]);
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you take out getURL function and keep it outside of FormBanners function?

Answer (score 0):

So in my example I had made many mistakes. Taking Arun's advice I separated the function out, which made debugging far easier.. it instead was not failing on the XMLHTTP Request because that worked fine, but firefox was crashing when debugging.

So my issues were that I was in the second part:

- Used the value of i for results (i was no longer defined)
- Getting the "_new_statusLookup_value" would only provide the guid of the lookup I would instead want "_new_statusLookup_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
- Lets not ignore the fact that because I had copied and pasted many iterations of this code that I was also using "results" instead of "result".

Many little mistakes.. but it happens! Thanks for the help, just goes to show.. typos are our downfall!